# C++ windows registry editing

Tags: c++, registry

hey i need c++ program to edit windows registry

Answer (score 5):

One good program is Regedit.exe.  It is probably written in C++.

Answer (score 1):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) has an excellent framework for editing registy - that is, [QSettings](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qsettings.html). And for bonus points, if you happen to change your mind and go Linux, your code would still work, storing your data in .ini-style configuration files.

Take note that Qt is very fat for a C++ library, but also very functional. There's a crazy lot you can do with it. I also absolutely recommend it for GUI.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a thousand small C++ wrappers for registry access. Of course I wrote my own, too. See the class `RegistryKey` in my [envvc](http://pesche.schlau.ch/2007/04/05/envvc/) [program](http://pesche.schlau.ch/files/envvc.cpp). It's only read-only access, but you'll get the idea.